# How to handle IDs when optimistically creating an entity in Redux?

Tags: javascript, redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a To-Do List app that creates a `TodoItem` by dispatching a `CREATE_TODO_REQUEST` action, which causes a middleware to make a`POST` request to an API and respond with `CREATE_TODO_SUCCESS` with the newly created `TodoItem` returned by the API. This `ToDoItem` has a messy hexadecimal ID (like `59e52a5ec8dae14f2420a9ef`) assigned to it by our database.

The problem is, sometimes the API could take a few seconds to respond (especially if the user is on a weak connection), so I'd want to optimistically update our application state with the new `ToDoItem` before the server is done processing it.

This pattern gets messy because all my `TodoItem`s are indexed by ID in my `Redux` store, and their order is stored in a list of IDs. These IDs are generated by the API after a `ToDoItem` gets created.

```
{
    byId: {
       59e52a5ec8dae14f2420a9ef: {...}, 
       59e52a5ec8dae14f2420a434: {...} 
    },
    ids: [
       '59e52a5ec8dae14f2420a9ef', 
       '59e52a5ec8dae14f2420a434'
    ]
}
```

**My question is, what `ID` should I assign my eagerly-created `ToDoItem` while I wait for the API to return the newly created `ToDoItem` with a proper ID?** Is there an established pattern for handling this type of situation?

I could use a random number generator to create a provisional ID and replace it with the real ID when the `CREATE_TODO_SUCCESS` action is dispatched (see sample app state below).

```
 {
        byId: {
           59e52a5ec8dae14f2420a9ef: {...}, 
           59e52a5ec8dae14f2420a434: {...},
           "provisional-todo-1": {...}  // this is being created on the API rn
        },
        ids: [
           '59e52a5ec8dae14f2420a9ef', 
           '59e52a5ec8dae14f2420a434',
           'provisional-todo-1'
        ]
    }
```

But this might require some complex logic keeping track of which provisional `ToDoItem` is associated with actual `ToDoItem`s that are later returned from the server. Additionally, there is the complexity associated with making sure actions dispatched against provisional `ToDoItem`s (marking as complete, editing, deleting) are applied to the correct "real" `ToDoItem`s after they are created.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is to create an local object with a mapping to the remote id.

For example, it might look something like this:

```
class Todo {
  constructor() {
    this.id = 'local' + Todo.globalId;
    Todo.globalId += 1;
    this.remoteId = null;
  }

  resolve(remoteId) {
    this.remoteId = remoteId;
  }
}
Todo.globalId = 0;
```

In redux, you could store these Todo objects, and use those internally to track your state. Then, when the API finally comes back with a value, you can set the remoteId. If there is some failure you could remove the local object or perhaps set a flag.